# XCode: How can I check the URL type on every page load in UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiwebview, hyperlink

I need some sample code to check if the page is 'file', 'http' or 'www' on the page load. At the moment the code is as follows;

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    //CAPTURE USER LINK-CLICK.
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
        NSURL *URL = [request URL];   
        if ([[URL scheme] isEqualToString:@"file"])  {
            [webView loadRequest:request];
            [homebutton setHidden:YES];
            NSLog(@"Opened File");
            return NO;
        }

        else if ([[URL scheme] isEqualToString:@"http"]) {
            [webView loadRequest:request];
            [homebutton setHidden:NO];
            NSLog(@"Opened External Page");
            return NO;
        }

        else if ([[URL scheme] isEqualToString:@"www"]) {
            [webView loadRequest:request];
            [homebutton setHidden:NO];
            NSLog(@"Opened External Page");
            return NO;
        }
    }        
    return YES;  
}
```

I want it based around this but this is only when a link is clicked and I want it to apply when a form is filled out and then the form redirects to another page etc...

I would really appreciate a quick answer,

Thank you very much,

James Anderson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you need to check out the various `UIWebViewNavigationType` listed in the "constants" section [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! I've done that and everything works now but how can I enable zoom only if the file is www or http?

Comment: Please see the "scalesPageToFit" property of web view in its class reference.

Comment: OK, all working from that perspective but the checking URL type on page load doesn't work any more for some reason? Is there another way to do it? Can you post some sample code please?